# How to convert node.js code to regular browser javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know how to get a javascript file to work for web-browser functionalit, when it's coded as node.js.

The code in question is from a github [graphenejs-lib](https://github.com/svk31/graphenejs-lib). I want to convert this node.js code into js:

```
import {Apis} from "graphenejs-ws";
var {ChainStore} = require("graphenejs-lib");
Apis.instance("wss://bitshares.openledger.info/ws", true).init_promise.then((res) => {
    console.log("connected to:", res[0].network);
    ChainStore.init().then(() => {
        ChainStore.subscribe(updateState);
    });
});
let dynamicGlobal = null;
function updateState(object) {
    dynamicGlobal = ChainStore.getObject("2.1.0");
    console.log("ChainStore object update\n", dynamicGlobal ? dynamicGlobal.toJS() : dynamicGlobal);
}
```

There is another github from the same developer, [steemjs-lib](https://github.com/svk31/steemjs-lib), that shows both the node.js use, and the browser use in the README default page.

I don't know how to make graphenejs-lib into browser javascript, like the steemjs-lib has been made into a regular javascript working version.  I contact the dev, but have yet to receive a response.

I figured other people actually know how to do what the dev did for steemjs-lib, and get the graphenejs-lib to work in a browser.

Can you help me out? Thank you.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle which generates an error for the Api when I added the file ```https://wzrd.in/standalone/graphenejs-ws@latest``` and code ```var {Apis} = graphenejsWs;```, that doesn't seem to be the right call: ```Uncaught (in promise) Error: Api not found``` jsfiddle.net/rhwmgLta

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to help you with that:

Note that not all of the Node's APIs will be available in the browser.

Answer (score 6):

Use browserify. https://wzrd.in/ will package it for you if you just want to use that one library. https://wzrd.in/standalone/graphenejs-lib@latest

```
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/graphenejs-lib@latest"></script>
<script>
  const {ChainStore} = graphenejsLib;
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the ```import {Apis} from "graphenejs-ws";``` ?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle which generates an error for the Api when I added the file ```https://wzrd.in/standalone/graphenejs-ws@latest``` and code ```var {Apis} = graphenejsWs;```, that doesn't seem to be the right call: ```Uncaught (in promise) Error: Api not found```  https://jsfiddle.net/rhwmgLta/

Comment: You probably want to use a version already built at https://github.com/svk31/steemjs-lib/tree/master/build. Try using https://rawgit.com/svk31/steemjs-lib/master/build/steemjs-lib.js in JSFiddle.

Comment: "The code in question is from a github graphenejs-lib. I want to convert this node.js code into js..." from the OP. Not for steemjs. The OP also shows the code in question, that is in node.js format, and I'm asking for regular JS. Here is the graphenejs-lib.js file: https://github.com/svk31/graphenejs-lib/tree/master/build